# Why are constants declared with `let`?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, keywords

A few weeks ago, I went on Udemy course on Swift, the instructor mentioned that constants are called `let` in Swift because it's standard in OOP (JavaScript uses it for example).

I know this may seem like a really stupid question, but I think it is confusing that constants are declared by `let`. As, let doesn't stand for constant.

Where did the `let` keyword come from?

Comment: Do you have an example of a language or some code where `let` is used specifically for constants?

Comment: What language are you talking about? The far most popular one that uses `let` to declare variables is Javascript, but in Javascript a variable declared with `let` is not in fact a constant.

Comment: Swift another example.

Comment: I was told in a tutorial that let is common convention. Also why the -1?

Comment: Sorry, I will try better.

Comment: Rust is one, I think?

Comment: It seems to simply be a combination of the ideologies that "variables should be declared with `let`" and "variables should be constant by default."

Comment: Opinion based? I was asking the naming origins, wasn't a judgement or opinion of it. Wasn't asking "What does everyone think about let?"

Comment: Your confusion is understandable since Swift is the odd language here in how it uses `let`. The keyword is not common in OOP languages, as Swift and JavaScript are the only ones using it. This is more a tradition for declaring variables from “functional languages” which got the tradition from mathematical writing conventions. But that doesn't have to concern you. *Any* programming language will have some weird design choices.

Comment: Let being for a variable predates Javascript - see the original Dartmouth BASIC so predates any OOP language

Comment: This is more on topic for Retrocomputing - if you put the question more as which language forst used let to define a variable.

Comment: I still don't understand the question being closed for being an opinion.

Comment: Because “let” and “var” each have three letters so you can change a variable from const to non-const without changing any formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the keyword `let` to declare constants is *not* a general convention. The keyword `let` is used that way in Swift, Rust and Haskell, but in Javascript it denotes a regular variable (just one with a special scope).

As for where the use of `let` to declare variables come from, it's a very old tradition for mathematical proofs:

[image: A proof in group theory using lots of "let"s]

(Source, due to popular demand: [https://www.maths.tcd.ie/~dwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Theorems.html](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Edwilkins/LaTeXPrimer/Theorems.html))

Answer (score 1):

The use of `let` *for a constant* is simply a combination of two factors:

- The use of `let` for variables (as Michael Borgwardt explained)
- The belief that variables should be immutable (constants) unless specified otherwise.

In JavaScript, `let` declares a variable which is mutable (not a constant).
In Haskell, `let` declares a variable which is immutable. That's because *all* variables in Haskell are constant.
In Rust, `let` declares an immutable variable and `let mut` declares a mutable variable. This is because the designers of Rust wanted to make variables immutable by default - they wanted you to take extra time to think "do I really need `mut` here?" in the belief that this will reduce the number of bugs you create.

Comment: `Let` is common throughout functional programming languages, including the ML family (SML, Ocaml, Haskell) and the Lisp family starting with Scheme. It's definitely not common in OOP languages though, despite what OP's instructor alleges.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to go *(koff, koff ...)* much earlier than that, in the original Dartmouth `BASIC` language, "everything had to begin with a verb."  So, originally, it had to be `LET A=4`.  But it didn't take very long for people to realize that the grammar could just as easily be coded to make the keyword optional.

But – since that time –  various subsequent language-designers have picked-up on that same word, and unfortunately they have used it in many and inconsistent ways.  "So it goes," I guess.